# Remote desktop from Windows to MacBook Pro with custom display resolution

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

I have a MacBook Pro I got from work and I want to remote connect to it from my pc. I did it with UltraVNC Viewer but I cannot set the resolution to the native one of my monitor. I also noticed it is more of a TeamViewer (screen sharing) thing rather than Windows Remote Desktop.

Any way I can make it work like the Windows RDC?

Comment: No. They are based on very different protocols - see https://superuser.com/q/389144/347380 and https://superuser.com/q/296642/347380

Comment: @Tetsujin so there is no way to have the effect I need?

Comment: Windows Remote Desktop (RDP) doesn't send the *contents* of a window so much as it sends the information to *recreate* the window on your computer. Apple, in it's infinite wisdom, decided to do remote access differently than MS and used VNC. Which sends (and this is over simplified) a *picture* of the remote computer's desktop. So you are stuck with whatever resolution the remote computer is set to.

Comment: Windows RDC is used to remote from mac to computer running windows operating system and resolution could be chosen under display tab. But for tools used to remote from windows for mac, it depends on the settings it configured. Take TightVNC example, users are allowed to change the resolution inside the remote connection.
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/remote-access-mac-osx-windows-7/
https://superuser.com/questions/184338/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-vnc-server-without-restarting-it